# MySQL, ORDER By not working

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

First I've made a simple guestbook, now I want that the last comment shows up at the first place on the site. My plan was to sort rows from the database in an descending order, by Date or by ID. Here's the code snippet:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `guestbook` ORDER BY `Date` DESC") or die("Mysql error: " . mysql_error());
```

This code don't causes any errors, but the comments are shown as the first time. 
I've copied the code from phpMyAdmin too, but the result is the same.
The type of ID is of course INT with `auto_increment`, and the type of Date is `VARCHAR` (I've stored the date and the time in one variable).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are aware that there is a perfectly usable `DATETIME` field, or even `TIMESTAMP` that returns formatted dates?

That aside, it's almost certainly caused by you have a format other than big-endian for your dates.

Try `ORDER BY id DESC` instead - it'll be much faster since it's a unique (preferably primary) key .

Comment: I've tried this before...i can't explain why this code not work... :/ thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, but "it not work" is not a helpful statement to make. What happens?

Comment: I'm sorry... The comments are shown as the first time, just like the sentence in my question :(

Comment: So you tried `ORDER BY id DESC` and it still showed them ordered by increasing ID?

Comment: Please show the full query you are using, with `ORDER BY id DESC`.

Comment: Here is the code and the fetch_array:
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `guestbook` ORDER BY `ID` DESC") or die("Mysql error: " . mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `guestbook`") or die("Error");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ...

Comment: The heck? You're querying by ID descending, then completely ignoring that query and doing ANOTHER query that has no ordering (and so defaults to ID ascending). Assign the first query to `$result` and get rid of that second one.

Comment: Yees...that's it! I'm new in PHP and MySQL, so I don't understand the logic completely yet... This is a good lesson for me ;) Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Date` column to be a `DATETIME` column type and it will sort correctly.

Sorting on a `VARCHAR` will depend on the format you have stored the data.

Comment: I've changed this before, but then I become just zeros like this:
00/00/00 - 00:00:00

Comment: The dates you have stored must be in the wrong format to convert directly to a DATETIME. You may need a slightly more involved process to update the table - possibly parsing the VARCHAR field and inserting the properly formatted DATETIME into a new column. After that, remove the current Date column and rename the new one you just created which has the correct DATETIME data in it. You will also need to update any code which inserts these records to use the correct DATETIME format. The NOW() function in MySQL makes this easy to insert the current time.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll try this in a few hours, it's 5 am in the morning in Croatia... Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Try  this: 
    SELECT * FROM `guestbook` ORDER BY `ID` DESC

instead of your date,if you want your date order correctly make sure your date datatype is datetime.

Best Regards

Comment: I've tried this, but with no effort :( but thank you for the answer!

Comment: please post your column definition.. :)

Comment: ALTER TABLE `guestbook` CHANGE `ID` `ID` INT( 3 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT